# Should I write 3 separate autobiographies?

Tags: style, technique, non-fiction, biography

I have started writing my autobiography. I am going to describe 3 very important life events.

Now, should I write about all three life events in one book or should I write them separately?

Comment: Autobiographies are only in volumes because you're telling a richly-lived life in minute detail. It depends on what these three events are and how much you're going to write about them.

Comment: I just cannot help it... Every time I see this question, the Beatles song "I Me Mine" runs through my head.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to describe one important event in one book, then that's not an autobiography; it's a memoir. There's absolutely nothing wrong with that, and you can certainly include information about your life aside from that event in the book.

An autobiography would be the entire story of your life to date, and you would generally go into less detail on each event, focusing less on the event itself and more on the way that event affected your life.

If you have three significant events to write about, I think you could justify writing *four* books - three memoirs, one about each event, *and* an autobiography.

Answer (score 2):

An autobiography will generally tell your whole life up till now, you wouldn't write a whole book for a single event.

Furthermore, you'll want to include more than just three events if you're going to draw people into the story of your life and see how you develop as a person.

Is there a compelling reason why people would want to read your autobiography? Usually people who write autobiographies do so because they are have had a highly eventful life, something out of the ordinary.

It's worth considering what will make your autobiography compelling to read and ensuring that is a clear theme throughout. Also, consider the development of the story, how your life and personality changes over time.

This is perhaps wandering from the point of your question but is hopefully helpful.

Comment: +1 While I agree with you, I know a person who wrote an autobiography concerning one event in her life (helping her young daughter fight cancer). She has since turned a new page in her life and I could imagine her writing a second autobiography focusing on that new 'adventure'. If the OP is thinking about similar major events, I could see two (or three) separate (partial) autobiographies being penned.